# How to use font without ligatures via WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create simple application with custom output. I'm using CreateFont function in order to load monospaced font with specific options. As a result, the text has been drawn (DrawText) with ligatures such as fi.

How to disable this?

*I am very sorry for my bad English*

### Creating font

```
normal = CreateFont(char_height, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, 0, 0, 0,
                    RUSSIAN_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
                    CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 5, 
                    FIXED_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Menlo");
bold = CreateFont(char_height, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, 0, 0, 0,
                  RUSSIAN_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 
                  CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, 5, 
                  FIXED_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Menlo");
```

### Printing

```
void Console::Print(string text, int color, int weight) {
    RECT r;
    r.top    = padding + temp_y * (char_height + space_y);
    r.bottom = r.top   + char_height;
    r.left   = padding + temp_x * char_width;
    r.right  = padding + length();
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    SetTextColor(hdc, color);
    SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(43, 48, 59));
    SelectObject(GetDC(hwnd), weight == WEIGHT_NORMAL ? normal : bold);
    DrawText(GetDC(hwnd), text.c_str(), text.length(), &r, DT_LEFT);

    temp_x += text.length();
}
```

Current output (note the word *"offline"*):

[image: Current output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you are asking. Can you provide a snippet of your code and a screenshot of the output?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added some information

Comment: Please post screenshots inline, don't post links (that are broken, BTW).

Comment: @n0rd I'm sorry. Links fixed. I can't post images because of my reputaion.

Comment: You did not show the code that is calling `Print()`, or the code that is setting up the values you are using to position the drawings. Please always provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That being said, `Print()` is leaking `HDC` handles.  Every time you call `GetDC()`, you need to call `ReleaseDC()`.  Your calls to `SelectObject()` and `DrawText()` should be using your existing `hdc` variable.  Call `GetDC()` once, and then call `ReleaseDC()` when done using that `HDC`.

Comment: Just don't use an Apple font on Windows.  Use DejaVu or Consolas.

Comment: Are you sure the string you sent in is using separate characters and wasn't somehow preprocessed to refer to a ligature?

Comment: It seems extremely weird that a monospace font both has ligatures and has metadata to select those ligatures.  Note:  https://github.com/powerline/fonts/issues/42

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is full **source code [link](http://pastebin.com/Md1NMzXC)**. I'm just learning to work with WinAPI so there can be a lot of mistakes.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy yes, I'm sure. Link of source code is here in comment above.

Comment: @HansPassant but if I want to use exactly this font?) Is in WinAPI option like in CSS `font-variant-ligatures: none;`? Or must I choose another font or change this font with aid of font editor?

Comment: Where did you obtain this font?

Comment: @RossRidge I don't remember. Maybe font was downloaded from Github repo.

Comment: Maybe try finding another version of it, or another font that looks like it, and see if that works.

Comment: @RossRidge I have downloaded this [font Meslo](https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font). It is very similiar to Menlo. Yes, there is no trouble with ligatures, but I don't think this is solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem seems to be that your font is broken.  I'm not sure why a monospace (fixed-pitch) font would have ligature information.

## Solution 1

Use [ExtTextOutW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713(v=vs.85).aspx) with `ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE`.  You may lose other functionality (like bi-di, digit substitution, shaping for complex scripts), but it does seem to prevent kerning and ligation, so it may be suitable for your purpose.

```
::ExtTextOutW(hdc, x, y, ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE, &rc, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), nullptr);
```

I tested with the font Gabriola, since I don't have Menlo or Meslo.  Gabriola is a variable pitch font, but it has distinctive ligatures that make it easy to spot, especially `fi`.

## Solution 2

A second approach, which has the same drawbacks, is to draw the strings character by character with TextOut in a loop.  This is a little trickier because you have to worry about Unicode surrogate pairs, clipping, and updating the current position.

```
const auto old_alignment = ::SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_UPDATECP);
const auto old_mode = ::SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
::MoveToEx(hdc, x, y, nullptr);
// Loop simplified for demo.  This doesn't handle Unicode surrogate pairs.
for (auto ch : msg) {
    ::TextOutW(hdc, 0, 0, &ch, 1);
}
::SetBkMode(hdc, old_mode);
::SetTextAlign(hdc, old_alignment);
```

This produced identical results to the first solution.

## Non-Solution

Note that my earlier idea to use [GetCharacterPlacement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144860(v=vs.85).aspx) without the GCP_LIGATE flag followed by [ExtTextOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162713(v=vs.85).aspx) with ETO_GLYPH_INDEX does not work.  The glyphs returned from GetCharacterPlacement still included ligatures even without the GCP_LIGATE flag.

```
// DOES NOT WORK
GCP_RESULTSW results = {sizeof(results)};
WCHAR modified[64] = L"";  // FIXED BUFFER LENGTHS JUST FOR TESTING
results.lpOutString = modified;
int deltas[64] = {0};
results.lpDx = deltas;
WCHAR glyphs[64] = L"";
glyphs[0] = 1;
results.lpGlyphs = glyphs;
results.nGlyphs = ARRAYSIZE(glyphs);

const DWORD flags = GCP_REORDER;  // but not GCP_LIGATE or GCP_USEKERNING
::GetCharacterPlacementW(hdc, msg.c_str(), msg.size(), 0, &results, flags);
::ExtTextOutW(hdc, x, y, ETO_GLYPH_INDEX, &rc, glyphs, results.nGlyphs, deltas);
```

Comment: "I'm not sure why a monospace (fixed-pitch) font would have ligature information" - many do. Consider [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode).  It's especially useful for programming: on that site, look at how the x in hex 0x0 changes, or how comparison operators !=, ==, <= etc render.

Comment: @David M:  I don't know if "many" fixed-pitch fonts do this.  Fira C0de is pretty specialized for a particular task, and it looks like those two-character ligatures still take up two columns, which makes more sense in a fixed-pitch font than something like the `fl` ligature in the OP's font.

Comment: That's fair - if I could edit the comment I'd remove "many".  I've seen this [moderately highly voted](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/12918189-add-ligatures-to-consolas-font) VS UserVoice requesting ligatures for Consolas, too, and I guess the combination of Fira Code + maybe-Consolas + [Pragmata Pro](https://www.fsd.it/shop/fonts/pragmatapro/) + a few others, ten tops, became "many". It's an interesting thing for code fonts. Polarizing. Many editors have an option to turn it off.